# How to stop typing at certain length in Redux form text field?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I want a validation for my add credit card form, in which I want that the user should be unable to type in after 16 character in text field. What is the best way to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Input
      value={this.state.cardNo}
      onChange={event => {
        if (event.target.value && event.target.value.length <= 16) {
          this.setState({ cardNo: event.target.value });
        }
      }}
    />;
```

Use state and check length is <= 16 then only setState else leave and put state value in input value and while submitting value u can submit from state.

**Note:** You don't need to use redux just for client side validation.

In case of redux forms:

[use this reference](https://davidkpiano.github.io/react-redux-form/docs/guides/validation.html)

```
import { actions } from 'react-redux-form';

function emailIsValid(email) {
  // terrible validation, I know
  return email && email.length > 0;
}

// in the connected component's render() method...
const { dispatch, user } = this.props;

return
<input type="text"
  onChange={(e) => e.target.value.length <= 16 && dispatch(actions.change('user.email', e))}      
/>
```

My suggestion is not to use redux forms that will gives a lot performance issues